# Converting string to float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I want to convert the strings into float value but there is a comma (",") with some values which needed to be removed.

I tried this:

```
new_df = new_df[['Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen']].str.replace(',', " ").astype(float)
```

but it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: We can't create dataframes from images. Please post code that creates the sample dataframe instead of an image.

Comment: pandas `series.str.replace()` only works on series objects, not whole dataframes. Iterating through your columns and doing the replacement on each in turn is one way to solve it

Comment: What is `new_df.dtypes`? The columns without commas are likely floats.

Comment: This is a screenshot of the text file I am using as my dataframe. should I copy-paste the txt file here?

Comment: @UcchashSarkar yes, you should usually do so.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `replace` with `regex=True` option:

```
new_df = (new_df[['Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen']]
               .replace(',', '', regex=True)
               .astype(float)
         )
```

Or use `apply`:

```
new_df = (new_df[['Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen']]
               .apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', ''))
               .astype(float)
         )
```

Comment: Its not `regex=True` that fixes the problem (its using `DataFrame.replace`) and since regex is slower than string replace it should only be used when needed. Otherwise this is a greate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `str` method only in pandas series.

You can try this for several columns:

```
new_df = new_df[['Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen']].apply(lambda x : x.replace(",","").astype(float)
```